# SQL Reuse Select Clause with Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I reuse Select Calculations?

Currently, my select looks like this:

```
SELECT
  (sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3)) * 0.1 as TOTperc1,
  (sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3)) * 0.2 as TOTperc2
FROM ....
```

How can I reuse the summary of this calculation as a variable so I can use in both Selects?

```
(sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3))
```

So the final Select Would look like this:

```
DECLARE @TOT as something = sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3);

SELECT
   @TOT * 0.1 as TOTperc1,
   @TOT * 0.2 as TOTperc2
FROM ....
```

**UPDATE:**
The question had `mysql` as a tag by mistake, and you may find answers that are not relevant to mssql, but they may be correct for `mysql`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking, show us an example of what you want to do, even if its just pseudo code for now

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated it, I don't know if it is better now.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Only tag the database engine you are using.

Comment: PLease dont spam tags, if yo are using MSSQL dont also add MySQL they are different

Comment: Yes it was my bad

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in a subquery

```
select s * 0.1 as TOTperc1,
       s * 0.2 as TOTperc2
FROM (
  SELECT
    (sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3)) s
  FROM ....
) t
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to have

```
(sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3))
```

as a variable for the two calculation parts.

I would solve this in the following way:

```
SELECT
   (sum(TOT1) - sum(TOT2) - sum(TOT3)) as total,
   total * 0.1 as TOTperc1,
   total * 0.2 as TOTperc2
FROM ....
```

Comment: I tried that but I am receiving `Invalid column name 'total'.`

Comment: Which database system are you using? Because if you use sqllite it might just be total, without the as keyword.

Comment: Maybe it's not working because it is on mssql